# Need help to sort an arraylist of arrays

Tags: java, list, sorting, arraylist

I have an arraylist which holds arrays of double values and I want to sort the rows for example by the third value in the field.

Is there a smart way to do it? (ascending/descending)

declaration:

```
private List<double[]> row = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

example:

- 10.0, 5.0, 200.3
- 9.1, 1.4, 3.3
- 1.1, 7.6, 3.4

sorts by the second column (asc)

- 9.1, 1.4, 3.3
- 10.0, 5.0, 200.3
- 1.1, 7.6, 3.4

**EDIT!!**

later iam gonna try this but imo I have no time to test it! mby someone could verify this

```
    if (sortDir == SortDirection.ASCENDING) {
        Collections.sort(tabelle,new Comparator<double[]>() {
            public int compare(double[] array1, double[] array2) {
                return Double.compare(array1[colIds.indexOf(aColId)], array2[colIds.indexOf(aColId)]);
            }
        });
    }
    if (sortDir == SortDirection.DESCENDING) {
        Collections.sort(tabelle,new Comparator<double[]>() {
            public int compare(double[] array1, double[] array2) {
                return Double.compare(array1[colIds.indexOf(aColId)], array2[colIds.indexOf(aColId)]);
            }
        });
    Collections.reverse(tabelle);
    }
```

wow soo many comments :D thanks

Comment: First what have your tried?

Comment: Yes, call `Collections.sort` providing a custom comparator and compare the second value of the arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java 8:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws IOException {
    final List<double[]> row = new ArrayList<double[]>();

    row.add(new double[]{10.0, 5.0, 200.3});
    row.add(new double[]{9.1, 1.4, 3.3});
    row.add(new double[]{9.1, 1.4, 3.3});

    final List<double[]> sorted = row.stream().
            sorted((l, r) -> Double.compare(l[2], r[2])).
            collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Or, if you want to sort in place:

```
row.sort((l, r) -> Double.compare(l[2], r[2]));
```

Comment: +1 Or if you want to sort the original list, `row.sort((l, r) -> Double.compare(l[2], r[2]));`

Comment: @ZouZou, indeed - will add to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`Collections.sort()` can take a `Comparator`.

See the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 0):

using `Collections.sort()`

```
List<double[]> row = new ArrayList<double[]>();

row.add(new double[] { 10.0, 5.0, 200.3 });
row.add(new double[] { 9.1, 1.4, 3.3 });
row.add(new double[] { 1.1, 7.6, 3.4 });

Collections.sort(row, new Comparator<double[]>() {

    @Override
    public int compare(double[] o1, double[] o2) {
        return Double.compare(o1[1],o2[1]);
    }
});
```

Comment: You can use `Double.compare` instead.

Comment: Supported since Java 4.

Comment: @ZouZou Is there any significant performance difference between these two ways?

Comment: Well you're creating two `Double` objects with `valueOf` and then `compareTo` will call `Double.compare` internally with the double values hold by the objects you just created, so I expect it to be slower.

Comment: @ZouZou `Double#compareTo(Double)` internally calls `Double.compare(double,double)`. I think second one more better than first in terms of performance hampered by primitive wrapper and object construction.

Answer (score 0):

hi I have made a function which takes list of arrays, and the Position of column which is to be compare and short the list...

```
public void tobeShorted(List<double[]> l, int c){  //short the list by column wise comparision
        for(int i=0; i<l.size()-1; i++){ //using Bubble short Technique 
            double[] current1=l.get(i); //get the current array
            for(int j=i+1; j<l.size(); j++){
                double[] current2=l.get(j); //get the next array
                if(current1[c-1]<current2[c-1]){ //compare the element of the given POSITION(not index) of arrays
                    l.remove(j);l.add(j, l.get(i)); //remove and add rows
                    l.remove(i);l.add(i, current2); //remove and add rows
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I have check it and it is working and it short the list in Descending Order....I wish it may help you...!

Comment: This is an interesting learning exercise, but nothing more than that. Bubble sort should **never** be used in production code. Moreover handwritten short algorithms shouldn't be used (unless you have a very good reason). Further, if your method is passed a `LinkedList` rather than an `ArrayList` then the performance goes from the (already terrible) `O(n^2)` to something in the order of `O(n^4)`.